# At least one one object must implement Icomparable

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I am attempting to get unique values in a list of similar value distinguished only by a one element in a pipe delimited string...  I keep getting at least one object must implement Icomparable.  I don't understand why I keep getting that.  I am able to groupBy that value... Why can't I find the max... I guess it is looking for something to compare it with.  If I get the integer version will it stop yelling at me?  This is the last time I am going to try using LINQ...

```
    var queryResults = PatientList.GroupBy(x => x.Value.Split('|')[1]).Select(x => x.Max());
```

I know I can get the unique values some other way.  I am just having a hard time figuring it out.  In that List I know that the string with the highest value amongst its similar brethren is the one that I want to add to the list.  How can I do that?  I am totally drawing a blank because I have been trying to get this to work in linq for the last few days with no luck...

```
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xDoc.LoadXml(node.OuterXml);
                string popPatInfo = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("./template/elements/element[@name=\"FirstName\"]").Attributes["value"].Value + ", " + xDoc.SelectSingleNode("./template/elements/element[@name=\"LastName\"]").Attributes["value"].Value + " | " + DateTime.Parse(xDoc.SelectSingleNode("./template/elements/element[@name=\"DateOfBirth\"]").Attributes["value"].Value.Split('T')[0]).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                string patientInfo = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("./template/elements/element[@name=\"PatientId\"]").Attributes["value"].Value + "|" + xDoc.SelectSingleNode("./template/elements/element[@name=\"PopulationPatientID\"]").Attributes["enc"].Value;// +"|" + xDoc.SelectSingleNode("./template/elements/element[@name=\"AdminDate\"]").Attributes["value"].Value;
                int enc = Int32.Parse(patientInfo.Split('|')[1]);
                if (enc > temp)
                {
                    lastEncounter.Add(enc, patientInfo);
                    temp = enc;
                }
                //lastEncounter.Add(Int32.Parse(patientInfo.Split('|')[1]));

                PatientList.Add( new SelectListItem { Text = popPatInfo, Value = patientInfo });
            }
```

I was thinking about using some kind of temp variable to find out what is the highest value and then add that string to the List.  I am totally drawing a blank however...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I get the IDs in an anonymous type to make it readable.

```
var patientEncounters= from patient in PatientList
                       let PatientID=Int32.Parse(patient.Value.Split('|')[0])
                       let EncounterID=Int32.Parse(patient.Value.Split('|')[1])
                       select new { PatientID, EncounterID };
```

Then we group by UserID and get the last encounter

```
var lastEncounterForEachUser=from pe in patientEncounters
                             group pe by pe.PatientID into grouped
                             select new 
                                    { 
                                        PatientID=grouped.Key,
                                        LastEncounterID=grouped.Max(g=>g.EncounterID)
                                    };
```

Comment: In that select list Item right, the value has Patient Ids, and encounter ID's.  The highest encounter ID would be the last encounter.  There could be several items in the initial list that are all the same patient (same Patient ID... But there could be several different Patient ID's as well).  But each value of the SelectListItem has a that encounter ID.  The highest one is the latest encounter.  I want the last encounter for EACH patient ID and I want those in a list...  I was thinking first group by patient ID right, then select the max of those encounter ID's.

Comment: Is this correct?
    patient.Value.Split('|')[0] is PatientID     
    patient.Value.Split('|')[1] is EncounterID

Comment: Sure thing. Just stepped away for a minute.

Comment: I was able to try it and it works. Remember though it will return an anonymous type. You should create a class if you want to pass it around.

Comment: I think it worked.  I just need to get the results back into the selectListItem's some how.

Comment: Getting the ID's Back is ok, but I guess I will have to reconstruct the List from XML.  Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3304/discussion-between-dmainevent-and-ufuk-haciogullari)

Answer (score 3):

Linq doesn't know how to compare 2 `Patient` objects, so it can't determine which one is the "greatest". You need to make the `Patient` class implement `IComparable<Patient>`, to define how `Patient` objects are compared.

```
// Compare objets by Id value
public int CompareTo(Patient other)
{
    return this.Id.CompareTo(other.Id);
}
```

Another option is to use the `MaxBy` extension method available in Jon Skeet's [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) project:

```
var queryResults = PatientList.GroupBy(x => x.Value.Split('|')[1])
                              .Select(x => x.MaxBy(p => p.Id));
```

EDIT: I assumed there was a `Patient` class, but reading your code again, I realize it's not the case. `PatientList` is actually a collection of `SelectListItem`, so you need to implement `IComparable` in that class.

Comment: I don't understand why I Couldn't just drill it down to the Int32.Parse(Value.Split('|')[1]) and have it compare that.

Comment: @DmainEvent, I'm not sure I understand what you really want to do... In the `Select` call, x is a `IGrouping<SelectListItem>`, so its items are of type `SelectListItem`. You could find the max by `Int32.Parse(Value.Split('|')[1])`, but it wouldn't really make sense, since all items in the same group have the same value for this

Comment: Patient is simply a select List item.  I have the highest value in the Value string.  I just split it out.  I have seen this DLL and I am really weary placing somebody else's dll in my production code.  That is very bad form in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe I should Group by the first split and get the max by the second split.

Comment: "I am really weary placing somebody else's dll in my production code": so you never use any third party libraries ?!

Comment: Only with Jquery.  Don't you think it is really dangerous using other people's code in PRODUCTION environments.  This isn't a school project here.  If I can't see what is in it, then I won't use it.